# Div Content Overflowing

Tags: html, css

I'm having quite an issue here with a website.

The blue div container is having issues. Content from the next `<li>` is spilling into the current `<li>`.

How do I stop this?

CSS for area:

```
#strip {
    background:#039;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#strip ul {         
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

#strip li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    height: 247px;
    overflow:hidden; 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

go to #strip li then make the width the same as your div's(#strip) width.

Comment: for some reason, doing that seems to blanket the #strip, hence, the slider doesn't show

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this, it works perfectly with this solution.

Comment: You are setting the width of #strip with javascript, right? You need to set the width of the li's to the same width using the same method because you are floating them.

Comment: Nope, the width is set using CSS as above.